# Calling btmgmt in the background not working

Tags: bluetooth

When I SSH into a machine and run `btmgmt find` it "works" in the sense of producing output.

However when I run this command instead via

- a cron job, or
- a script I'm detaching from a cron job, or
- a script I'm executing and detaching from my SSH session

it doesn't produce any output, not even an error message.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be related to a known bug (https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-bluetooth/msg85222.html) in `btmgmt` where it just fails silently if no interactive stdin is present / is disconnected. An easy workaround is doing:

```
yes | btmgmt
```

Comment: I would have never figured that one out, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using some Linux distribution, are you redirecting the output to a file when using a cron job or script?
By default cron emails the output to the user owning the cron job.

Please see https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html

> Cron examines all stored crontabs and checks each
> job to see if it needs to be run in the current minute.  When
> executing commands, any output is mailed to the owner of the
> crontab (or to the user specified in the MAILTO environment
> variable in the crontab, if such exists).  Any job output can
> also be sent to syslog by using the -s option.

Also, if you are running the script in the background then the stdout needs to be redirected to a file for you to examine the output.
For ex.

`/my/home/script.sh >> output.txt 2>&1` - this would redirect the output and error messages to output.txt file under /my/home

Comment: Yes! I'm redirecting both stderr and stdout to separate files.

Comment: please can you show the code/command that you are running? It will be helpful. Also the OS you are using, btmgmt version.